# Prove that $\int^\infty_0\cos(ax^2) dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8a}}$ using Cauchy's theorem $\oint_C f(z)dz=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

The question starts by asking to show that $e^{iaz^2} \xrightarrow{} 0$ and is analytic as $|z| \xrightarrow{} \infty$, for $0 < \arg{z} \le \frac{\pi}{4}$, which I have done. NB $a$ is a real, positive constant.

It then continues as follows:

> By applying Cauchy's theorem to a suitable contour prove that:
>   $$\int^\infty_0\cos(ax^2) dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8a}}$$

Since $z^2=x^2-y^2+i2xy$, it is clear that the question wants the above equation proven by integrating $e^{iaz^2}$ along some contour $C$ and using Cauchy's theorem, which will hold within the argument range given above (because the function is analytic in this range). However, I don't know how to select an appropriate contour. If $0 \le \arg(z)$ then it would be a lot easier, but because $0<\arg(z)$ the contour has to be a lot more awakward (because we cannot use the $x$ axis).

I have attempted to use the following contour:

[image]

Reason being that the contour segment $C_2$ is simple and $C_\infty$ won't contribute anything to the integral because the function is 0 at infinity.

If we now apply Cauchy's theorem:

$$\oint_C e^{iaz^2}dz=\int_{C_1} e^{iaz^2}dz+\int_{C_2} e^{iaz^2}dz=0$$

$$\int_{C_1} e^{ia(x^2-y^2)-2axy}(dx+idy)+\int_{C_2} e^{ia(x^2-y^2)-2axy}(dx+idy)=0$$

$$\int_{C_1} e^{ia\frac{3x^2}{4}-ax^2}(dx+i\frac{dx}{2})+\int_{C_2} e^{i2ax^2-2ax^2}(dx+idx)=0$$

$$\int^\infty_0(1+\frac{i}{2})e^{ax^2(\frac{3i}{4}-1)}dx+\int^0_\infty(1+i)e^{2ax^2(i-1)}dx=0$$

I have no idea where to go from here. It is clear that I must use De Moivre's theorem, but the resulting integral would be hideous, which makes me doubt my contour. Either my understanding is wrong, my contour is poorly chosen or the question just wants me to wade through pages of tedious algebra. I would appreciate any guidance you could offer.

Comment: Simpler to not split into $x$ and $y$. A straight line through $z=0$ can be parametrized by $z = e^{i\theta} t$ with $t$ real. The integral of a function $f(z)$ along this line would be $\int_0^\infty f(e^{i \theta} t) e^{i\theta} {\rm d}t$.

Comment: Why not keep $C_2$ as is, and let $C_1$ be the positive $x-$axis?

Comment: @Winther I need to split it into $x$ and $y$ to show what the question is asking for.

Comment: $f(z)\to 0$ as $\lvert z\rvert\to\infty$ alone doesn't guarantee $\int_{C_\infty} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\to 0$ for your arc $C_\infty$.  Example: $f(z)=1/z$.  You really need to bound the rate of decay.

Comment: Why? You don't have to. What I tried to say is that the line $C_2$ can be more easily written as $z = e^{i\pi/4} t$ with $t$ real (this is the same as saying $y=x$). From this it follows directly that $dz = e^{i\theta/4} dt$ and $z^2 = e^{i\pi/2}t^2 = it^2$ so the integral along this lines simply becomes $-e^{i\pi/4}\int_0^\infty e^{-at^2}{\rm d}t = -\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8a}}(1+i)$. You are free to use $x$ and $y$ if you want, but personally I think it's much easier this way (and as said above and below you should let $C_1$ be the $x$-axis from which the result follows).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you @Winther that made the algebra considerably easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still "use the $x$ axis".

Replacing your $C_{\infty}$ with $C_r$ the arc of $|z|=r$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{C_r}e^{iaz^2}dz\right|&=\left|\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\exp(iar^2e^{i\phi})ire^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|&&\text{[substitution $z=re^{i\phi}$]}\\ &\leqslant r\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\exp(-ar^2\sin\phi)\,d\phi&&\text{[taking $|\cdot|$ of the integrand]}\\ &\leqslant r\int_0^{\pi/4}\exp(-2ar^2\phi/\pi)\,d\phi&&\text{[using $\sin\phi\geqslant 2\phi/\pi$]}\\ &=\frac{\pi}{2ar}(1-e^{-ar^2/2})\underset{r\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
\end{align}
The rest is clear.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. I have one quick question before I mark this answer as accepted: why can we use the $x$ axis when the function is not analytic on it as $x$ tends to $\infty$? From my understanding the function being integrated must be analytic everywhere on and within the contour for Cauchy's theorem to hold.

Comment: First, the contour is taken with an arbitrary but *fixed* $r$, and the integrand is analytic in the entire complex plane, so the theorem holds for sure - we have an *exact equality* for each fixed $r$, and the problem is to prove that we get what we expect when $r\to\infty$ (we do, because the integral along the $x$ axis converges to what we need by definition, the integral along $x=y$ converges to a known one, and the remaining integral converges to $0$ as shown above).

Comment: Second, I don't understand what do you mean by a function analytic when $z\to\infty$ "with some restriction" (like $0<\arg z<$ whatever). A function can be analytic at $z=\infty$, but it's not the case for $\exp(iaz^2)$.

Comment: Thank you - your first comment cleared up my confusion. As for your second comment, the function is analytic within only some range of $\arg(z)$ as $|z|$ tends to $\infty$, which may or may not be the same thing as tending $z$ to $\infty$, I'm not sure.